# SQL - Get top value for each user (DISTINCT ?)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct

I have a MySQL table containing `userID`,`score` . 
A single user can have many scores, but there can be many users, of course.

I want to retrieve the highest score **for-each** of the `userID`'s in the database.

I've tried the following but I feel like i'm in the wrong way :

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT(`userID`), `score` FROM `myTable` ORDER BY `score` DESC
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Shai.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the aggregate function `max` with the `group by` clause:

```
select
    userid,
    max(score) as maxscore
from
    mytable
group by userid
order by maxscore desc
```

The `group by` says, "Hey, MySQL, get me the max `score`, but partition it by `userid`." This way, you get the max score for each `userid`.

Additionally, you can `order by` the aliased column so you get the list of users by max score, descending (for a leaderboard or what have you).

Comment: Was just missing the max(score), Thanks!

Comment: @ShaiMishali - And the `group by` :)

Comment: @ShaiMishali - Also see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: yeah i know i meant that i've tried all sorts of things with DISTINCT and with GROUP BY, but forgot about the MAX part :) Thanks!